# что значит "определить кол-во элементов каждый их которых больше суммы остальных элементов своего столбца". Это я не понимаю или тут опечатка?

Tags: c++

Задание - Дана матрица А[N][М], состоящая из целых чисел, записанная в текстовый файл.
Структура файла следующая: сначала хранится п и m, а затем матрица А. Определить
количество элементов, каждый из которых больше суммы остальных элементов своего
столбца и записать это значение в отдельный файл в виде номер столбца - Количество
элементов. Содержимое файлов вывести на экран.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Да всё просто и плоско, как блин... Считаешь сумму столбца. Берёшь половину. Все элементы этого столбца, значение которых больше это половины - отвечают заявленному критерию. По итогам суммируешь количество таких элементов в каждом столбце, получаешь нужный результат.

Comment: а откуда половина взялась? в задании же написано "суммы остальных элементов",а не "суммы остальных элементов на пополам"

Comment: @vilsan - это уже в сторону алгоритмов решения задачи нужно смотреть. По факту такая логика позволит быстро прийти к верному решению. Сама задача может решаться разными в том числе логическими способами.

Comment: @vilsan Не поверишь.. но если от суммы элементов столбца отнять один элемент - получится сумма остальных элементов... можешь проверить. А если этот один больше половины, то сумма остальных (вот опять поверь на слово) меньше этой половины.

Comment: Если `s` — сумма всех элементов, а `x` — проверяемый элемент, то тогда `s-x` — это сумма остальных элементов. И нам нужно проверить, что `x > s-x`, что равносильно `2x > s`, что равносильно `x > s/2`. Вот и половина.